# Using DFT to study Hydrogen Evolution Reaction on a surface?

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, computational-chemistry, surfaces, hydrogen-bonds

How well can DFT, as implemented in VASP, describe surface reactions?

For example, I want to study the hydrogen evolution reaction (HER) on the $(111), (110), (100) \text{ and } (011)$ surface planes of Cobalt (III) Phosphide $\ce{CoP}$. Assuming I have optimized bare surface geometries, can I expect reasonable energetics for hydrogen production using DFT calculations of the energy and surface bound geometries?

Comment: Challenges compared to what? Compared to other software packages? Compared to reactions other than HER? Compared to other kinds of materials?

Comment: I mean the challenges inherent in using DFT itself. For example, it is known that DFT is not good in finding the band gap of most materials. In this case, what are the possible challenges that could be encountered in using DFT to study the HER of the mentioned Transition Metal Phosphides in general (and the mentioned surface planes of Cobalt (III) Phosphide in particular)?

Comment: I see. I know basically nothing about CoP (esp. whether it is a narrow-gap semiconductor or even a metal), but I guess that compared to the intrinsic errors of the DFT method, surface reconstruction and leaching may be even bigger problems. Phosphides are generally labile under acidic conditions (or even in neutral water) and tends to release PH3. While the bulk material CoP may be stable under such conditions, it's hard to say whether there will be one or two layers of the phosphides near the surface that will be leached. And that will make a big difference in the catalysis

Comment: Thank you very much @wzkchem5 for your response. Any other persons with helpful insights should kindly post their answers please. Thanks

Comment: @thehereandnow There's plenty of challenges when using DFT. Maybe it would help if you could tell us why you're interested in knowing what the challenges are?

Comment: Understanding the challenges of Hydrogen Evolution Reaction (HER) of Cobalt (III) Phosphide (CoP) would help better understand the principles/mechanisms that govern the (HER) of CoP which would lead to more efficient generation of Hydrogen via electrolysis. Secondly I use CASTEP tools (in Materials Studio) for my simulations where I use single (atomic) Hydrogen to represent the Hydrogen(s) that are being adsorbed to the surface of (CoP). I want to ask if this is correct or should I be using molecular (H2) Hydrogen instead? @Phil Hasnip and everyone your contributions would be highly appreciate

Comment: @thehereandnow I tried to edit the question to narrow it down to a particular portion of the analysis of this reaction. I think the initial question may given too many possible things to answer (e.g. can DFT optimize the geometry of the surfaces, could DFT accurately/efficiently calculate transition states) as well as requiring a lot of specific knowledge beyond DFT about $\ce{CoP}$ and how you are modeling the reaction itself (e.g. how should hydrogen be represented on the surface). Let me know if I have changed the question too much and we can come up with a different formulation.

Comment: @thehereandnow I didn't see your reply to me because you didn't use the @ symbol to ping me.

Comment: @thehereandnow Have you checked the recent literature on the simulation of surface electrochemistry (eg concept of computational H electrode)? From your brief description, I am not sure what you try to do. Also when you ask about "description of the reaction", exactly what properties are you talking about? Overpotential? Kinetic parameters? Or is it a more general question if you can use DFT at all or not?

Answer (score 3):

Your initial question is quite broad, and there are many sub-questions that DFT calculations may or may not be able to answer. For example, DFT is useful for studying trends in reaction kinetics vs. reactivity of materials. There are many examples of this in literature.

For example, trends in calculated surface reactivity across metal phosphides correlated with observed HER kinetics: https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2015/ee/c5ee02179k

It is harder to be confident in getting "reasonable energetics", as you put it, for a particular adsorption thermochemistry. Trends and differences in adsorption thermochemistry have often been found to be insightful, as in the linked study.
This is a bit of a broad answer to a broad question.